# R - use user input file in terminal

Tags: r, terminal, user-input

I wrote a simple script that takes a csv file as input, does some operations, and returns a txt file.

```
1 bpseq <- read.csv(file = "/home/Desktop/bpseq.csv", header = FALSE)
2 names(bpseq) <- c("posi", "res", "posj") #bpseq has 3 columns
3 df <- data.frame(posi=integer(nrow(bpseq)),
4                 ...
5                 posj=character(nrow(bpseq)))
6 df$posi <- bpseq$posi
7 df$posj <- bpseq$posj
7 write.table(df, file = "/home/Desktop/bpseq_CLnotation.txt", col.names = F, row.names = F, sep = "\t")
```

This works just fine and I can run it successfully in command with "Rscript mybeautifulscript.R".

But I want the user to be able to choose the input file!
I tried of course

```
bpseq <- read.csv(file.choose())
```

And it works just fine when I run it in RStudio but I want my colleagues, non-friendly towards R, to be able to run it in terminal.

From the error this returns I understand that file.choose() is not the way to do this! The function is reading my next line of code assuming it is the file, when it is names(bpseq), line 2 in the added code.

[Nathalie](https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) wrote a good related answer that helped me in some points but I still don't know the correct way to get an user input file in command line. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
Add to my code lines -1 and 0 and change line 1 in previous segment of code:

```
-1 args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
 0 fn <- args[1]
 1 bpseq <- read.csv(fn, header = FALSE)
```

Run in terminal as such:

```
Rscript mybeautifulscript.R inputfile.csv
```